# Do any one know what’s The name and model of this vehicle?

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, car

[image]

Hello

I had this car as gift ! Can any one help me know what the name, modle of this car and the price?

Comment: To me at least then it looks like something custom made that may have started life as a boat. Can you ask the person who gifted it to you?

Comment: It’s  a Heinz 57 - as the parts come from allsorts...

Comment: I cant ask  please if someone know tell me

Comment: Most engines have the maker's name on them - start with that.

Comment: Is that a pink fuzzy lollipop driving that vehicle?

Comment: It's a sandrail - custom built, probably with a VW or Subaru engine at the back. The price is... whatever someone will pay for it. If it was a gift, you'll make money.